# Mocha test runner - option to rerun only failed tests from previous run

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, gulp-mocha

Is there an option in Javascript's Mocha test runner to only run tests which failed on the previous run?  Is there an easy way to implement that if not?  There are a lot of words written about retrying flaky tests but thats not what I want.  I want to run tests, see failures, make updates to the code, then automatically run only the previous failed tests to see if my changes fixed them

Answer (score 1):

Found this https://github.com/segmentio/mocha-broken but integration into WebStorm wasn't streamlined enough so dropped it...

Might fit your needs though, worth a try